# Creating a java server with rest

Tags: java, sockets, rest

I need to create a rest server and client.

I stumbled upon this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) which uses sockets.  I want to be able to use REST calls, possibly HTTP, because the clients will be actually in different languages.

Instead of using `Socket` api from `java.net.*` what should i use ? if i use Socket API can I use c++ and php to communicate with this server? or should i go with REST?

any directions appreciated.

Comment: [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) really only makes sense in the context of HTTP. You can definitely use the _principles_ behind REST using a self-written API that runs directly over raw sockets, but it wouldn't be REST at that point.

Comment: well i want to be able to communicate over HTTP. but not sure which API to use. possibly on a custom port.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a lot of things you can use to create rest services, and then they can be consumed by almost anything. Of particular awesomeness is the ability to hit them in your web browser, just because we're all so familiar with them.

When I need a 'quick and dirty' rest solution, I use [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org) - I won't claim it's the only solution, but it's the easiest I've ever worked with. I've literally said in a meeting "I could have XYZ up in 10 minutes." Someone else in the meeting called me on it, and sure enough, using Restlet I was able to get a functioning REST server running with the (very simple) features I said I would get in the meeting. It was pretty slick.

Here's a barebones server that has one method, returning the current time. Running the server and hitting `127.0.0.1:12345/sample/time` will return the current time.

```
import org.restlet.Application;
import org.restlet.Component;
import org.restlet.Context;
import org.restlet.Restlet;
import org.restlet.data.Protocol;
import org.restlet.routing.Router;

/**
 * This Application creates an HTTP server with a singple service
 * that tells you the current time.
 * @author corsiKa
 */
public class ServerMain extends Application {

    /**
     * The main method. If you don't know what a main method does, you 
     * probably are not advanced enough for the rest of this tutorial.
     * @param args Command line args, completely ignored.
     * @throws Exception when something goes wrong. Yes I'm being lazy here.
     */
    public static void main(String...args) throws Exception {
        // create the interface to the outside world
        final Component component = new Component();
        // tell the interface to listen to http:12345
        component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 12345);
        // create the application, giving it the component's context
        // technically, its child context, which is a protected version of its context
        ServerMain server = new ServerMain(component.getContext().createChildContext());
        // attach the application to the interface
        component.getDefaultHost().attach(server);
        // go to town
        component.start();

    }

    // just your everyday chaining constructor
    public ServerMain(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /** add hooks to your services - this will get called by the component when
     * it attaches the application to the component (I think... or somewhere in there
     * it magically gets called... or something...)
     */
    public Restlet createRoot() {
        // create a router to route the incoming queries
        Router router = new Router(getContext().createChildContext());
        // attach your resource here
        router.attach("/sample/time", CurrentTimeResource.class);
        // return the router.
        return router;
    }

}
```

And here's the 'current time resource' that it uses:

```
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
import org.restlet.representation.StringRepresentation;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

/**
 * A resource that responds to a get request and returns a StringRepresentaiton
 * of the current time in milliseconds from Epoch
 * @author corsiKa
 */
public class CurrentTimeResource extends ServerResource {

    @Get // add the get annotation so it knows this is for gets
    // method is pretty self explanatory
    public Representation getTime() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        String nowstr = String.valueOf(now); 
        Representation result = new StringRepresentation(nowstr);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to understand something, i m interested in creating a server, just like HTTP server, with JAVA, custom, that will listen to incoming connections through REST calls. can i use Restlet for that?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with Restlet.

Comment: +1 Hi, Can you provide a sample link for creating Restlet http server for RESTful service?

Comment: @NitinJS I added a barebones server implementation to my answer. This uses the latest version of Restlet. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

[JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) is the API for REST in Java.  There are a lot of implementations, but the main ones are Jersey (the reference implementation), Apache's CXF and Restlet.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you don't create a server. You create a web application and deploy it on the server or servlet container. Some servlet containers are embedable into your web application, e.g. Jetty. Poppular free servlet containers are Tomcat, Glassfish, Jetty, etc.

For Restlet, it is not a servlet container. It is a framework that allow you to create a wep application with RESTful styles. So this should not be confused.

If you decide to use servlet container, then the problem is how you can create a web application with the RESTful styles. REST is not a technology - it is a design principle. It is a concept of how you should create the interface.

The design of REST is stateless so you do not need to store the state of the transaction. All information from a request should be sufficient to produce a respose to client.

There are several servlet framework that allows you to implment the REST styles easily. Some of them are very sophisticated, e.g. Spring framework.

Comment: But how are you implementing a Spring Boot Rest Server with a Socker Client Server peer?

Answer (score 1):

Download JBoss 7. Problem solved.

Heres a restful service:

```
@Path("/myservice")
public class MyService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaTypes.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String echoMessage(@QueryParam("msg") String msg) {
        return "Hello " + msg;
    }
}
```

Create a WAR. Deploy. Open up browser and go http://myserver/myapp/myservice?msg=World. Done!

Comment: Who told you that? JBoss 6 had serious performance issues but other than that the series has always been solid. JBoss 7 is a killer.

Comment: do i need a jar for that? which API do i use to do this?

Comment: i have only access to jboss 4. i work for a corp. i cant use jboss 7 :(

Comment: JBoss 4? Wow thats too bad, didn't think anyone still used that. You can implement your own REST based services using a Servlet framework but thats going to be a lot more work.

Answer (score 0):

I would say go with an HTTP based RESTful service. It's rapidly becoming a defacto standard. Check my answer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629870/network-communication-options-in-java-client-server/7630519#7630519) for pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best one out there. Spring MVC which has lot of REST capabilities in itself. This takes just a single jar file to be included. And you are all set to use all it's capabilities. Even as simple as the below guy explained in JBOSS and much more flexibility as well.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-30-rest-example

Answer (score 0):

I use JBoss 6 with [RestEasy](http:///www.jboss.org/resteasy).  I have created a tutorial located [here](http://insanelycrazy.net/development/faces/viewarticle.xhtml?id=12).  I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You're also welcome to see my very simple example for REST server implementation [here](https://restafar.com/java-very-simple-rest-server/).