# How to create REST compatible servlet?

Tags: java, rest, gwt, servlets, request

I want to create a servlet which will be the REST compatible.
I do not want to use jersey library, I just need a simple servlet which will accept request using REST and then proceed request for extracting parameters. Then further I can call my server methods from the servlet.

OR

Is there is any, which I can use to write only servlet which is REST compatible and make client call by REST compatible URL?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8541642/101715

Comment: If Jersey is what you fear, try another lib. There are plenty of them like rest4j out there. Creating a good RESTful service without a framework is hard and time-wasting.

Comment: Try [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy). Easy as it sounds. If you want a deeper integration with GWT (not necessarily worth), try [RestyGWT](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST is not a protocol, it's an architecture style. HTTP follows REST principles, so if you "do HTTP right", you're doing REST.

Servlets are a great (though low level) way to do Web APIs (let's not call them RESTful, most aren't; REST-like maybe?) and you don't need anything else (JAX-RS or Spring MVC make things easier, but ultimately they're generally just running in a servlet environment)

What makes an API "RESTful" (or "REST-like") is more how you *design* it (what it looks like for those that use it) than how you implement it (the code than no one sees but you).

Answer (score 1):

As previous people has stated, REST is not a protocol, merely a format of handling URL requests.

If you want to get a simple REST Api going quickly, take a look at Spring Web MVC.
Setting up a controller is this easy:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myApi")
public class MyController {

    @Inject
    MyService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getProduct/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Product getProductById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return service.getProductById(id);
    }

}
```

This was just an example.
A complete tutorial on setting Spring MVC up, can be found here:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-annotation-example/

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing called as REST protocol, it is either called REST based API or REST based web service. Earlier communication with server use to happen via SOAP based web services, i.e. request and response used to be XML based. In today's world most of the server are implementing REST based web service. Here instead sending XML for request mostly request data is passed either as query parameter in URL or in body of the request just like POST.

So ideally REST based web service is also based on HTTP/HTTPS protocol.

To know more on this read following link 
http://rest.elkstein.org/